# Data structures linked list

Tags: algorithm, performance, data-structures, linked-list, big-o

I was asked to solve this out:

There are two singly linked lists.
I need to write a method which get those two linked lists and returns a pointer to the starting point where the suffix is the same in those two lists.

Example:

given:

```
1->2->4->6->8->10->15
2->4->8->10->15
```

the returned value would be a pointer to the member - 8.

But,
I need to do it without changing the lists or using more memory,
and - we need to scan the lists only once, means `T(n)=O(n)`.

Comment: This definitely looks like a homework problem. Stack Overflow does not do your homework for you. Write some code, try to get it working, then when you have a specific problem ask for help.

Comment: What programing language are you coding at?

Comment: Are the lists guaranteed to be sorted?

Comment: In you example, it should return 2 right? How will it be 8?

Comment: first - its not my homework.. im just helping my gf prepare for her exam today...

Comment: oh... and i dont need to answer in coding.. pseodocode will be great :) and btw i program in c / c++ / java .

Comment: oh and - it should return pointer to the 8 because from the 8 to the end all the values are equal in both lists.   \n lists aint sorted at all.

Answer (score 2):

1. measure the lengths of both lists
2. skip forward in the longer list until they're the same length
3. walk forward through both lists in step, and remember the nodes AFTER the last point where the lists have different elements.  These are the pointers you can return.

Now... I know you said that you only want to scan the lists once, and I have done it twice, but you *also* said that this means **T(n) = O(n)**, and that is *not* correct.

Scanning the lists twice is *also* in **O(n)** and is required to solve the problem without using unbounded extra memory.

Comment: This will take *at least* two passes over the lists.

Comment: @wildpasser As mentioned above, it takes exactly two passes -- one pass over each list to measure, and exactly one step over each item in (2) and (3).

Answer (score 0):

This is a psuedocode.. not Python code for that matter
take the two lists and let p1 point to longer list and p2 point to shorter list,

```
while p1->next!=NULL:
   if p1->value = p2->value:
      p1 = p1->next
      p2 = p2->next
   else:
      p1 = p1->next
      returnpointer = p1->next// if it happens that some elements are same towards end but not the last element.. p1->next would be pointing to NULL anyways and else.. it'll always be the element next to the last element which wasn't same
return returnpointer
```